# Como usar um projeto GitHub como base para um novo?

Tags: git, github

Estou tentando usar o projeto do [angular-phonecat](https://github.com/camilaavilarinho/angular-phonecat) como base para um projeto novo, e fazer modificações em cima dele, pq a estrutura é bem parecida com o que eu quero desenvolver e assim não teria que configurar e baixar tudo que preciso(npm, bower). Porém sempre que crio um novo repositório, fica como se fosse uma cópia do  repositório original e não consigo commitar minhas modificações para meu projeto. 
O que estou fazendo:

- Fork do projeto angular-phonecat
- Clone do meu fork
- Crio um novo repositório no GitHub
- Mudo o origin: `git remote set-url origin git://github.com/meu-repositorio-criado`
- `git fetch --prune` (Pesquisei que isso apaga as branches, mas não deu certo para o que eu quero)
- `git push`

Depois do push, o projeto do novo repositório fica igual ao angular-phonecat origial e eu não consigo enviar meus commits. O que fazer? Quero que o meu projeto seja independente, só com o 'esqueleto' do outro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faça o seguinte.

Clone o projeto e exclua a pasta `.git` em seguida, de forma que ele não mantenha as informações do Git após ser clonado:

```
git clone https://github.com/camilaavilarinho/angular-phonecat.git [nome-do-projeto] && rm -rf [nome-do-projeto]/.git
```

Crie um repositório para esse novo repositório, no Github. E então, informe no seu projeto qual o caminho do repositório remoto (esse que você acabou de criar):

```
git remote add origin [novo-caminho-do-projeto]
```

Depois disso, basta comitar e subir as alterações, que você não modificará mais o projeto original.

Comment: Essa opção --bare está pegando outros arquivos (hook, info, objects...) e não os arquivos do projeto (app, e2e-tests, scripts...)

Comment: Desculpe, é verdade, eu tinha um conhecimento errado da opção `--bare`. Alterei a resposta de forma que funcione para o que você precisa. :)